# python to check if list of int contains in data with ~

Tags: python

I have a list and item like below and want to check if any int in the item contains value  ~1~20448~3~22901~12214~27681~9920408~20013~19957~19993~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ we should get 1 else 0.

```
       my_list = ['4587','9920408','9920316']
       flag=0
       value=""
       for item in my_list:
            if '~1~20448~3~22901~12214~27681~9920408~20013~19957~19993~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~' in item and flag==0:
                 value == 1
            else:    
                 value == 0
```

Here in the list we have 9920408 and we have that value in the item and the output should be 1 .
But i am getting the below value.

```
      False
      False
      False
```

Could you please advise on this. Appreciate your support.

Comment: Don't you want to check it the other way, i.e.: `if item in '~1~2044(...)~'` ?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `'~1~20448~3~22901~12214~27681~9920408~20013~19957~19993~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~' in item`, what do you expect that to mean? What would it mean the other way around - i.e., `item in '~1~20448~3~22901~12214~27681~9920408~20013~19957~19993~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~'`? Which way corresponds to what you are actually trying to do? (Try it with simpler values. What do you expect to happen for `'1' in '1~2~3'`? What do you expect to happen for `'1~2~3' in '1'`?)

Comment: are you sure you want to check the long string in a small string. you are searching `~1~20448~3~...` stuff in smaller ones. If your case is the opposite just make `item in ~1~20448~3~...`

Comment: `value == 1` is a boolean expression, it's not setting value to 1 which would be `value = 1`.  You set `value = ""` so `value == 1` is always False

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. Please suggest a best approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tools Python provides:

```
my_list = ['4587','9920408','9920316']
st = '~1~20448~3~22901~12214~27681~9920408~20013~19957~19993~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~'
if any( m in st for m in my_list ):
    print( "One of them was found." )
```